# How to play one audio two times

Tags: javascript

I want to play one audio two times at the same time just like I click piano key twice, In my example when I press button A sound plays perfect but for example if I click it two times audio plays only once

```
            var x = document;
            x.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
                if (event.keyCode == 65) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    key1.play();
                }
            var key1 = new Audio();
            key1.src = "sounds/316898__jaz-the-man-2__do.wav";
```

```html
            <img id="first" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS3qvBPOUHOAwoXkHoMD-qrxPqXSacbKMQ6HU21xsqFDshGoOAUBQ">
```

Comment: In other words: if the button was clicked again while the sound is playing, it should restart it when finished?

Comment: No not restart, I want to play it while it's already playing without stop

Comment: What you are suggesting seems like introducing a bug! If someone clicked ten times they do not want the audio to play 10 times! Unless I misunderstand you

Comment: Have you ever pressed piano key? in my example when I press A two times it only plays once, and the second when first is done, I want sound to be played before first  click is done

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use two different instances of `Audio` to play them together
or create a new instance of Audio at every click to have more than two audio played together